# Trying to find max area of an island where water is 0 and land is 1

Tags: python, breadth-first-search

Trying to find the maximum size of an island, where 1 represents land and 0 represents water. land can be connected in the up, down, left, right direction.
So for the input

```
[[0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0],
 [0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
 [0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0],
 [0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0]]
```

I expect to get 6, but my code is outputting 3.
here is what I have:

```
def maxAreaOfIsland(self, grid: List[List[int]]) -> int:
    rowlen  = len(grid)
    collen = len(grid[0])
    q = collections.deque()
    visited = set()
    directions = [(-1,0),(1,0),(0,-1),(0,1)]
    islandsize = []
    if not grid:
        return 0

    def bfs(i,j):
        size = 1
        q.append((i,j))
        visited.add((i,j))
        while q:
            square = q.popleft()
            for x,y in directions:
                newx = square[0] + x
                newy = square[1] + y
                if newx in range(rowlen) and newy in range(collen) and grid[newx][newy] == 1 and (newx,newy) not in visited:
                    q.append((i,j))
                    size += 1
                    visited.add((newx,newy))
        islandsize.append(size)

    for i in range(rowlen):
        for j in range(collen):
            if grid[i][j] == 1 and (i,j) not in visited:
                bfs(i,j)
    if not islandsize or max(islandsize) == 0: 
        return 0 
    else:
        return max(islandsize)
```

Anyone know where my logic is failing here? I know there are other approaches available but this one is the most logical to me and I don't get why it would return 3.

Comment: Is this an assignment? Can you use libraries?

Comment: The innermost `q.append((i,j))` - should that be `q.append((newx, newy))`?

Comment: No libraries! Yes I am practicing random coding problems because I am bad. Sloth, yes that is correct. Weird thing, I can read what I wrote for an hour but the moment I put it on stackoverflow and risk getting embarrassed by really stupid errors, i catch them within the next 15 minutes haha. Thanks all, you're great

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that I was stupid and failed to append the newx and newy values, and instead appended the initial value.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).